# For excel, for multiple arguments in SUMIF how to add the criteria condition based on a cell address?

Tags: excel

`=SUMIFS(N2:N1032, L2:L1032, "<>Deferred", C2:C1032, "=Sprint 1.1",B2:B1032,>**AI3**)`

In this case the **AI3** is the Sprint Start date (cell address). If I normally put **">02/12/20"** it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `" "` around your logical operators and `&`.

You can concatenate the operator to a cell like this:

```
 =SUMIFS(N2:N1032, L2:L1032, "<>Deferred", C2:C1032, "=Sprint 1.1",B2:B1032,">" & AI3)
```